# Windows-сервис для мониторинга папки и загрузки файлов в БД

Tags: c#, многопоточность, windows-service

Стоит задача разработать сервис, который будет использовать в качестве входа папку на локальном диске и при появлении в ней файлов, сервис должен осуществлять их парсинг, после чего полученные данные укладывать в БД. Нюанс в том, что файлы приходят "парами" *(01012015.xml + 01012015.txt)*, и скидываются в папку круглосуточно по FTP.
Разрабытываю **Windows Service (C#)**.Пытался итеративно (каждую секунду) вызывать метод `EnumerateFiles` в папке, группировать их, затем парсить и полученные данные укладывать в БД. Однако в результате периодически выскакивают исключения (либо файл ещё не польностью загружен через FTP, либо к нему нет пары и т.п.). При добавлении многопоточности ошибок ещё больше.
Интересует, существуют ли какие-либо готовые решения на такой случай?

Comment: Вопрос немного не по теме - а зачем вам тут многопоточность, если все равно все ограничивается "однопоточным" I/O.

Comment: Парсинг файлов выполняется быстрее, чем процедура укладки данных в БД, поэтому на этом моменте можно распараллелить загрузку (открыв сразу несколько подключений)

Comment: а как быть с файлами, которые ещё не загрузились?

Comment: Оставлю тут: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @PavelMayorov пробовал использовать его, но он при добавлении файла в папку выкидывает по несколько событий сразу, и не совсем понятно, на какое реагировать..

Comment: @klutch1991 реагируйте на все и собирайте данные в список "к обработке". Отсечь дубликаты не проблема же?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*У меня была аналогичная задачка.*

В основном потоке программы делаете интерфейс и управление.

Сканирование папки с данными можно оставить в 1 служебном потоке - все равно все ограничивается "однопоточным" I/O (и соответственно только в нем решать изолированный вопрос сканирования папки). А вот укладчики в БД сделать воркерами, которых создать, например штук N и которым раздавать данные.

Я бы поколдовал с попыткой открытия файла на запись (или, как подсказывают,  `FileAccess.Read`, `FileShare.Read`). Пока он не загружен, ОС такого доступа к нему не даст. (тут могут быть и более правильные решения). И так же проверять парность. И только тогда добавлять файлы в список "для обработки", из которого разбирать их воркерами (с использованием крит.секции).

Comment: Не надо открывать его на запись, достаточно FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read

Comment: FileShare.Read - это достаточная гарантия того что параллельно никто в этот файл ничего не запишет

Comment: @PavelMayorov спасибо за подсказку! Вы не против включить это в ответ?

Comment: Господа, так вы можете подсказать мне минимальный алгоритм действий? :) Код мне не нужен. ПРосто направьте в нужное русло.

Comment: @klutch1991 вы работали с потоками, про пул задач, воркеров, крит.секции знаете?

Comment: Да, с языком у меня всё хорошо. Знаю и TPL и async, просто затык с самой идеей - как лучше реализовать.